# How to filter on the to field on Outlook 365?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

I'm using Office 365 with a custom domain, that is, as a business. I created an alias for my email address with a "_dev" suffix, so, my main address is pablo.fernandez@example.com and the alias is pablo.fernandez_dev@example.com with the goal of having that be the destination for the emails my app sends while developing, so that I could filter them out. But I'm having trouble creating that filter. Is it even possible?

I created this on the desktop version of Outlook:

[image]

which looks like this on the web one:

[image]

The problem is that it's not applying only to that email address, but it looks like it's applying to all my email addresses, so, it's sending all the email, whether it goes to pablo.fernandez@example.com or to pablo.fernandez_dev@example.com to the Dev Testing folder.

Answer (score 0):

It's true that Outlook will resolve name instead of email address.

Considering your situation, you may change to following rule description:

[image]